# Finite Dimensional Hilbert Space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

A while ago someone asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907606/in-a-hilbert-space-h-if-the-closed-unit-ball-is-compact-then-how-can-it-be-p). I really like what the accepted answer is trying to do. But, I am having trouble figuring out his justification for the first line in the proof: 
$$\bigcup_{x \in F} B\left(x+ \frac{1}{2} \right) = F+B \left(0,\frac{1}{2} \right)$$

If someone could elaborate, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: It is just a notation: $\{1,2\}+[0,\frac 1 2]:=\{1+[0,\frac 1 2]\}\cup\{2+[0,\frac 1 2]\}:=[1,1+\frac 1 2]\cup[2,2+\frac 1 2]$

Comment: @MarcoDisce so the post just dealt with $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No! Mine was just an example

Comment: @MarcoDisce what was meant by $B(x+1/2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first term contains a typo, it should read $B(x,1/2)$ instead of $B(x + 1/2)$. Moreover, $F + B(0,1/2)$ is the Minkowski sum, which is defined via
$$F + B(0,1/2) = \{x + y \colon x \in F, y \in B(0,1/2)\}.$$
Hence, this equality is essentially the definition of the Minkowski sum.